# making Desktop Flash AS3 Air application without installing AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mobile, air

Well the title say it all.

So far i've been using flash IDE and publish it as AIR to make desktop app. But the down side of this is that users have to install adobe AIR in their computer before they can use this app.

So:
1. Is there a way to make desktop app without users installing adobe AIR using Flash IDE (coz AS3 is my favorite lang so far).
2. Is there another language or software I can learn, so when ever I make desktop app or perhaps mobile app users can just install it in their devices whithout having to install anything else.

I need all the insights I can get, So thanx in advance to all you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since FlashBuilder 4.6 and Flash Professional CS6 you should be able to export your release build as "Signed application with captive runtime". If you choose so, the user will not need to install the AIR runtime.

Answer (score 0):

MDM Zinc as .exe file! or else. http://www.multidmedia.com/ also for desktop Apps. 
regards aktell

Answer (score 0):

Users cannot use AIR apps without having AIR installed.

But do you really need AIR functionalities? Because you can publish .exe files with Flash, which simply embed Flash Player inside. If you target Windows platforms and you don't need anything special from AIR - this is a good choice.

Other than that - there are a lot of languages that can publish desktop apps, just browse around. .NET is one of the most used ones.